# Historical ID lost can it be reclaimed

Tags: am-yisrael-jewish-nation, science, genealogy

Could it be possible that many Hispanics who moved from Spain and having their family line coming from Jewish blood (Sephardi Jews), be actually Jews and not know it? There is a test now to check Iberian people to see if they are Sephardi Jew, the Cohanim DNA (Y-Chromosomal Aaron DNA) Cohen Modal Haplotype (CMH) for short.

As well as many authors and professors who also agrees with this, one example from one well know author Mr. Camilo Jose Cela who worte : Judios, Moros Y Christianos (Jews, Moors and Christians) published in Spain in 1979. I would like to know, since I am proud of being Jewish if I am.

Comment: I'm confused.  What is your question?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, you feel you have Jewish ancestry, can you be considered Jewish?  Is that what you are asking?  A short answer, the basic definition of a Jew is a person whose mother is Jewish or has 
converted.  In cases like this, you need to consult a rabbi.  There are many cases of those who have 
claimed Jewish ancestry, but still had to undergo conversion.

Comment: I thought that the Spanish blood among Hispanics is primarily  through the fathers side (Conquistadors came to South America, needed a wife, so married a local). If so, the current Hispanics wouldn't be Jewish at all.

Comment: Also, DNA may not count in Halacha (I think we have questions about that here)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9938/dna-and-jewish-law

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of the [lost 10 tribes](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0019_0_19733.html)? When the Kingdom of Israel fell to the Assyrians, the 10 tribes that inhabited the kingdom were dispersed and lost from the Jewish world. They were exiled and they never came back. There was some hope that they'd come back after the ending of the [Babylonian](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/history/Ancient_and_Medieval_History/2500_BCE-539_BCE/Jerusalem_Destruction_and_Restoration.shtml) exile of the Kingdom of Judah, but they still did not come back. Centuries later, [Rabbi Akiva made a statement on the status of the lost 10 tribes of Israel](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1701071/jewish/Are-the-Ten-Lost-Tribes-Ever-Coming-Back.htm):

"The ten tribes will not return, as the verse says (Deuteronomy 29:27), 'And the L‑rd uprooted them from upon their land, with fury, anger and great wrath, and He cast them to another land, as it is this day.' Just as a day passes and it will never return, so too, they will be exiled never to return."

Further more, Rav Shimon ben Yehudah says:
"If their deeds are as this day’s, they will not return; otherwise they shall."

Essentially it depends on whether or not they repent according to him. Now why do I mention this? Because it plays a key roll into your question. Let's consider the descendants of "many Hispanics who moved from Spain and having their family line coming from Jewish blood" as a lost people. Let's put them on the status of a lost tribe because they have not been involved in the Jewish community for years and have assimilated into their surrounding culture. Even if you can show DNA tests proving that they have Hebrew blood, it does not make them Jewish. There needs to be a clear distinction between being Hebrew and being Jewish. As [R' Yochanan](http://megillatesther.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/esther-25-question-2-why-does-the-verse-call-mordechai-a-yehudi/) in the Talmud puts it, when Esther refers to Mordechai as a Yehudi, it means he actually fought against idol worship. He wasn't Yehudi because his father or mother was a Hebrew, [but because he stood up for his beliefs, and that's commonly how we use the word today to describe a Jew or Jewishness.](http://www.jewsofindia.org/PDFs/newsletters/Indian%20Jewish%20Congregation%20Newsletter%20Feb-2013.pdf)

So to conclude, it doesn't matter. Blood does not play a significant, major role on whether or not you're Jewish, especially if the last practicing Jew in your ancestry was many generations ago. They aren't Jews who don't know it, contrary to what many might say.

Comment: Are you saying that a Meshumad needs a full halachic conversion?

Comment: Well, yes. At the very least they have to do teshuvah or else they'll remain as k'goy.

Comment: There's a difference between Teshuva and Geirus. According to this answer, either a Jew whose a Meshumad needs geirus or a Goy could become a Jew through "Teshuva" (no Beis Din, MIkva)

Comment: If you're of the opinion that a descendant of a meshumad is a goy, then he needs a conversion. However, if you claim he's still a Jew, then he needs at least do teshuvah. I'm trying to reflect both thoughts.

Comment: Who holds of way #1?

Comment: You seem to imly that ancestry doesn't matter. I don't think that any source agrees.

Comment: Your last sentance isn't true either. If we have "Halachic" proof of Jewish ancestry, the child is Jewish (just has to do teshuva). There were many such instances after the Holocaust.

Comment: Shmuel Brin, if you're not shomer shabbos you're a goy (or more accurately, k'goy as stated in Shulchan Aruch). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3OYANfA99k&feature=youtu.be&t=1h23m10s

Also, it states they are not k'yisrael.
הַמִּינִים מִיִּשְׂרָאֵל, אֵינָן כְּיִשְׂרָאֵל לְדָבָר מִן הַדְּבָרִים.

I understand that with the enlightenment era it's been a special hobby to find Jewish blood and such, but I don't think this is reflected in halacha. And nobody debates that after so much intermarriage (goy women marrying Jewish males and such) that their descendants are Jewish.

Comment: After how many intermarriages does one loose being Jewish? And where's the source?

Comment: A non-Shomer Shabbos is a Goy for many halachas (though not all according to some), until he wants to do Teshuva. There is no "full blown conversion" necessary. Also, marrying his/her children is Muttar, unlike a Goy's

Comment: If you're a male and you marry a female then the Jewishness is lost in one generation obviously.

Comment: Though not the other way around, unlike the answer

Comment: And the question of Jewishness of peoples who haven't been in the community for generations (and have engaged in intermarriage) isn't something new. The Kaifeng Jews that came to Israel got a conversion and so did the ones from Ethiopia.

Comment: Genesis 17:14, Exodus 31:14, and other verses state requirements lest the people be cut off from his people. Just look at the translation of the word "yehudi." One who praises God. If you don't even believe in God then you fall into a special status. They are no longer Jewish, nor are they Ben Noachides nor gentiles, they are kofers and below all those other titles. Kofers cannot even offer at a sacrifice at a temple where even a pagan can (Hul 13b). Hilchot Teshuvah 3:6 even talks about their souls being cut off.

Comment: Mordechai are not genetically jewish? But he's jewish because he isn't worshipping idols? What about the muslims and christians?